# Send a Bundle over the network

Tags: android, android-networking

I'm trying to send a `Bundle` over a network from one device to another using `ObjectInputStreams` and such. The problem is that `Bundle` is **not serializable**. Is there a simple way to make this happen? I want to use `Bundle` because I can be sending all sorts of types (String, int, parcelables, lists, etc)

Comment: I would strongly recommend using anything other than `ObjectInputStream`, in the interests of control and cross-platform compatibility: JSON, XML, protobuf, Thrift, etc.

Comment: why cross-platform? it's only Android, there's no option for iOS, web, etc. for this application. But thanks for the advice

Comment: "it's only Android" -- it's only Android **today**. Talented programmers use on-the-wire data formats that offer flexibility for the future.

Comment: Performance may be an issue if a lot of data have to be send at a high rate. Format such as JSON may not be optimal in this case.

Comment: whats your use case exactly? Sounds like you need a wrapper like a Bundle?

Comment: What do you mean by "a wrapper like a Bundle"?

Answer (score 2):

You should not serialize a Bundle, because it does not guarantee version compatibility. So if you can make sure every device uses the exact same version you should be fine. But I really would not recommend this. Every api states that this should not be done!

> Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism. This class
>   (and the corresponding Parcelable API for placing arbitrary objects
>   into a Parcel) is designed as a high-performance IPC transport. As
>   such, it is not appropriate to place any Parcel data in to persistent
>   storage: changes in the underlying implementation of any of the data
>   in the Parcel can render older data unreadable.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html

But if you really want to do it, here is a way to implement it:

```
Bundle in = ...;
OutputStream os = ...

Parcel p = Parcel.obtain(); //create empty parcel object
in.writeToParcel(p, 0); //saving bundle as parcel
os.write(p.marshall()); //write parcel to stream
```

Comment: Yes I know Parcel does not work. I am looking for an alternative.. It may be something other than a bundle provided that I can use it to transmit  anything with it.

Comment: @Roque: "provided that I can use it to transmit anything with it" -- by definition, you cannot transmit "anything with it" for any value of "it". There are plenty of data structures, like open sockets, that cannot be be passed across process boundaries, let alone over a network.

Comment: Let's restrict 'it' to Java/Android's main types then. Float, String, Int, Arrays of these things..